# Blazor unmarshalled javascript interop isolation

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

Blazor has javascript isolation like so:

```
var module = await js.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import",./_content/MyComponents/exampleJsInterop.js");
await module.InvokeAsync<string>("showPrompt", message);
```

is it possible to combine it with unmarshalled calls? I would like to do something like this:

```
var module = await js.InvokeUnmarshalled<IJSUnmarshalledObjectReference>("import",./_content/MyComponents/exampleJsInterop.js");
await module.InvokeUnmarshalled<string>("showPrompt", message);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of today, there is not a solution for referencing unmarshalled JS modules, however you can do something like this to check if the `IJSUnmarshalledRuntime` is available for use:

```cs
// Check if the IJSRuntime is the WebAssembly implementation of the JSRuntime
if (JsRuntime is IJSUnmarshalledRuntime wasmJsRuntime)
{
    wasmJsRuntime.InvokeUnmarshalled<string, string, byte[], bool>("Download", fileName, contentType, file);
}
else
{
    // Fall back to the slow method if not in WebAssembly
    await DownloadModule.InvokeVoidAsync("Download", fileName, contentType, file);
}
```

More info on using the `IJSUnmarshalledRuntime` here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-5.0#unmarshalled-js-interop

Comment: ye thats what i'm using just wasnt sure if im not missing something, thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is possible now in .Net 6.
The change was discussed here [Github discussion](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/26588)

You can use a cast now for your module reference:

```
var module = await js.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import",./_content/MyComponents/exampleJsInterop.js");
if(module is IJSUnmarshalledObjectReference objRef)
{
    objRef.InvokeUnmarshalled<string, string, byte[], bool>("Download", fileName, contentType, file);
}
```

Using .Net 5 it is possible to use reflection to invoke some internal functions. The modules just have an additional parameter: long targetInstanceId. In my projects these ids began with 1 and incremented by 1 with every imported module. [Source](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c8ed7f319868ec8c9482be763849ff1c84d00caa/src/Components/WebAssembly/JSInterop/src/WebAssemblyJSRuntime.cs#L65)